# set network interface for strongswan

Tags: networking, ipsec, strongswan

I am using StrongSwan on Raspberry Pi with a LTE token which is handled as `eth1`. It works fine as long nothing is connected to the ethernet port (`eth0`).

Then StrongSwan wants to use `eth0` which fails.

I have already tried (several combinations) in `/etc/strongswan.conf`:

```
charon {
        install_routes = no
        install_virtual_ip_on = eth1
        interfaces_use = eth1
        interfaces_ignore = eth0
```

Which did not help.

The IP address for `eth1` is set via DHCP from the LTE. For nftables routing I am using already a shell script putting the IP address dynamically into the rules.